# How do you get specific numbers and assign it from your input

Tags: python-3.x

if i give the input
(15% of 500) this is the full input with string,
then i want to assign 15 to one variable and 500 to another please tell me how to do it im new, probably if something silly please tell

Comment: Welcome to SO. A good practice is to show what you have tried so far. If you need a starting point, look at string splitting/string manipulation in python. Do follow the question asking guidelines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be using `re.findall()` and list comprehensions:

```
from re import findall

str = "15% of 500"
arr = [int(number) for number in findall("\d+", str)]
a = arr[0]
b = arr[1]
```

This also casts the values into integers.

Comment: Thank you bro needed it a lot trying to create a ripoff version of wolframalpha without AI XD

Comment: what does \d+ do?

Comment: @nub You are welcome. ```\d+``` is a *regular expression* (thats where ```re``` is coming from). It controls what pattern ```re.findall()``` is looking for in ```str```. ```\d``` can be translated to ```[0-9]```, so all digits basically. The ```+``` means that it looks for 1 or more elements of that pattern following each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by doing this:

```
str = "15% of 500"
arr = []
arr = str.split(" ")
print(arr) # check what is inside the array
a = arr[0].replace('%', '') # get rid of %'
b = arr[2]
print(a,b) # check data
#If you want this data to be operated use int(), like so:
print(type(a)) #this will print <class 'str'>
a = int(a) # we convert a to an int
print(type(a)) # check type: <class 'int'>
```

Comment: We might throw in a type casting to integer as well in case the numbers are then supposed to be operated on in the later part of the code. Which I feel it would be.

Comment: @TanishqVyas as you mention, we can include a type convert so he can operate those values after